Seekable player with WebRTC
Currently I'm using streaming video from my camera to web app using Gstreamer, it sends the RTP packets through webrtcbin for WebRTC transmission.

However now I want to implement a way to send already recorded videos (mp4 files) via WebRTC to my web application.
But I want it to have seekable capabilities. Ex: like this 
How would I implement this behavior?
(I know WebRTC doesn't have this seekable capability since it's used in realtime communication)
Any suggestions?
I investigated about Kurento player but it seems I have to implement their media server as well.

For seekable video you would typically use DASH / HLS protocols.
They work using the same principle:

Video is cut into chunks of several seconds long
These chunks are saved to disk along with a "playlist" file which contains the list of chunks
Output directory is served via HTTP (using nginx or any other web server)
Playlist URL is passed to web video player
Browser loads and plays chunks on demand

For example, if using HLS, you can install hls plugin for chrome, and just open playlist url directly to see the video. The video would be seekable. To embed it on the web page you would use hls.js.
To cut video into chunks, you can use Gstreamer or FFMpeg. Since you already using GStreamer, take a look at hlssink2.
DASH is regarded as a more modern / flexible protocol, but the principle is the same. Both of them can be used for realtime streaming, but the latency is typically in tens of seconds.
